# Refactoring some Ruby Code

Tags: ruby

I need some help refactoring some ruby code. Im not keeping it DRY at all.

```
if potatoes
  if item.type != nil
    if item.has_stuff == false && (item.something_else).to_f >= (comparing).to_f
      # RUN JOB A
    else
      # RUN JOB B
    end
  else
    # RUN JOB A
  end
else
  # RUN JOB B
end
```

I just created random names for things.

Comment: What are you asking? All you have is if statements.

Comment: Usually `x != nil` is equivalent to `x` unless it's possible that `x` might be `false`. Additionally, `x == false` can be shortened to `!x`.

Comment: @tadman You mean "unless it's possible that `x` might be `false`".

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). I haven't been over there in a while but this sounds like their type of question.

Comment: @sawa Precisely, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell as it currently stands, migration would be rejected for being *hypothetical or example code*.

Comment: @theTinMan This is example code and would be off-topic on Code Review. Please read [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Comment: @theTinMan Also please read the comment by Mat'sMug two comments above yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if potatoes && (item.type.nil? || (item.has_stuff == false && (item.something_else).to_f >= (comparing).to_f))
  # JOB A
else
  # JOB B
end
```

But for such complicated logic, it might be better to pull part of that into a method

```
def item.has_some_property?(comparing)
  has_stuff == false && something_else.to_f >= comparing.to_f
end

if potatoes && (item.type.nil? || item.has_some_property?(comparing))
  # JOB A
else
  # JOB B
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if !potatoes
  # Job B
elsif item.type.nil?
  # Job A
elsif item.has_stuff != false
  # Job B
elsif item.something_else.to_f >= comparing.to_f
  # Job A
else
  # Job B
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you associate the jobs to external methods (defined elsewhere) you can keep it dry by using ternary operators, and using a different perspective, considering that the conditions are complementary... to keep the code more readable you can write the conditions on different lines, if you wish, or you should use a method to perform the checks (i.e. item.has_stuff == false && (item.something_else).to_f >= (comparing).to_f) if meaningful in your code...

A quick example:

```
def is_empty_and_something_less_than_something?(comparing)
   item.has_stuff == false && (item.something_else).to_f >= (comparing).to_f
end

job_a_conditions= potatoes && (item.type.nil? || item.is_empty_and_something_less_than_comparing?(comparing))
job_a_conditions ? job_a : job_b
```

The same conditions can be associated to a method, if re-used in your code.